# Mongo db validation rules makes my insert statement fail

Tags: mongodb, validation, nosql

This is a bit weird for me, I'm a newbie at mongo db.

I set the following validation rules through NoSQLBoster console:

```
let validator = [
    {language : {
        $type : "string",
        $exists : true
    }},
    {label : {
        $type : "string",
        $exists : true
    }},
    {text : {
        $type : "string",
        $exists : true
    }},
    {order : {
        $type : "int",
        $exists : true
    }}
  ];

db.runCommand( {
  collMod: "profile",
  validator,
  validationLevel: "moderate", //off | strict
  //validationAction: "warn" |"error"
})
```

Well, after adding the validator, I try to add the following document:

```
db.profile.insert({language: 'en', label: 'Born', text: '31 Dec 1983 - Jaén, Spain', order: 1})
```

What I pretend is to make all those fields mandatory. And even providing all of them and having the appropriate type, I always get the following insertion error:

```
{
"message" : "write failed with error: {" +
          "    'nInserted' : 0," +
          "    'writeError' : {" +
          "    \t'code' : 121," +
          "    \t'errmsg' : 'Document failed validation'" +
          "    }" +
          "}",
"stack" : "script:1:96" +
          "script:1:96" +
          "script:1:96" +
          "script:1:96",
"code" : {
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "nRemoved" : 0
}
}
```

Now it became curiosity...
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my issue. I only had to NumberInt() function to wrap the integer. Otherwise it is considered as a float number. The following worked as expected:

```
db.profile.insert({language: 'en', label: 'Born', text: '31 Dec 1983 - Jaén, Spain', order: NumberInt(1)})
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

This is by design.

**Details**

```
The mongo shell treats all numbers as floating-point values by default.
The mongo shell provides the NumberInt() constructor to explicitly specify 32-bit integers.
```

Source: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/#numberint